# Shorten JQuery Snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery snippet:

```
(someVar.next().length == 0)?someVar.fadeOut().end().find("ul").first().fadeIn():someVar.fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
```

There is a fair amount of code duplication between the two results of the conditional - i.e. someVar.fadeOut() and .fadeIn() on both.

I would ideally like something like this:

```
someVar.fadeOut().((someVar.next().length == 0)?end().find("ul").first():next()).fadeIn();
```

But that doesn't work :)  Safari developer tools reports a syntax error but I'm not skilled enough to work out how to do it properly.

If it can't be shortened, then just saying that is fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I removed the `.end()` because I don't see a use for it.</s>

Otherwise, I just moved `.fadeOut()` into the conditional test.

```
(someVar.fadeOut().next().length == 0) 
?  someVar.end().find("ul:first").fadeIn()
:  someVar.next().fadeIn();
```

Or maybe this?

```
var $in = (someVar.fadeOut().next().length == 0) 
           ? someVar.end().find("ul:first")
           : someVar.next();
$in.fadeIn();
```

---

**EDIT:** As noted by *@T.J. Crowder*, I was not correct in removing `.end()`. I didn't realize that it continues to work if you start a new chain with the previous result. Makes sense though. Fixed.

Also, I had somehow reversed the second example. Fixed.

---

**Another EDIT:**

The second example could be further simplified like this:

```
((someVar.fadeOut().next().length == 0) 
           ? someVar.end().find("ul:first")
           : someVar.next()).fadeIn();
```

---

**One more EDIT:**

Another possibility is to simply `.fadeIn()` the `.next()` either way, which will have no effect if its `length` is `0`:

```
if(someVar.fadeOut().next().fadeIn().length == 0)
     someVar.end().find("ul:first").fadeIn();
```

Comment: Re the `end`, we don't know what filtering he's ending, it could be from before the code he's quoted... Good switch of `.find("ul").first()` to `.find("ul:first")`, though, that should be a bit more efficient.

Comment: @T.J. - Yes, you're right. I thought `.end()` would only work in the current chain, but it seems to work for the result of a previous chain stored in a variable. I'll update.

Comment: Yep, I had done a previous find() call so the end() is needed :) Thanks for the help

Comment: @Richard - I added one more possible solution. It removes the need for an `else` because it does a `fadeIn()` on the `.next()` in the conditional test. This should be harmless, because if the `length` is `0`, there's nothing to fade.

Comment: I moved the fadeOut() and next() calls to the previous line (where the elements are selected), changed (someVar.length == 0) to (!someVar.length), moved fadeIn() to outside the brackets at the end and changed .end.find() to just selecting from scratch and so ended up with:

((!someVar.length)?$("#someID ul:first"):someVar).fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

Not by much, no — or at least, not in a reasonable way (there are games you can play with strings and bracketed notation, but they would make your example worse, not better). You could move the `fadeOut` to its own statement:

```
someVar.fadeOut();
(someVar.next().length == 0)?someVar.end().find("ul").first().fadeIn():someVar.next().fadeIn();
```

...but after that, the chaining goes in different directions.

See also [my community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771033/shorten-jquery-snippet/3771146#3771146).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somewhat off-topic and so I'm making it a CW, but: When things get long like this, can I just put in my bid for good old-fashioned `if/else` statements?

```
someVar.fadeOut();
if (someVar.next().length === 0) {
    someVar.end().find("ul").first().fadeIn();
}
else {
    someVar.next().fadeIn();
}
```

About eight times easier to read and maintain, IMHO.